# VBA Outlook code to open Mail Item and Save As text

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm receiving Outlook mails that have other Outlook mails (*.msg) as attachments. I need them in txt format (or anything else Word can open).

I seem to have two choices:

1) Save the attachments to my drive as text files, rather than msg files. I have no idea how to do that, either manually or by code.

2) Save the attachments as msg files (I got a macro here on SO that does that), then open each file and save it at txt. But **File-->Open** in Outlook 2010 has no option for opening msg files. The only way I can see to open the file is to (manually) view the folder in File Explorer and double-click it. Once its open, I can use **File-->SaveAs**.

3) I could open and save the file in VBA. Or can I? (It seems you can't record a macro in Outlook the way you can in Word or Excel, or I would have tried it.)

EDIT: I tried Dmitri's suggestion, and this seems to work:

```
 Dim oNamespace As NameSpace
 Dim oFolder As Folder


 ' Get a reference to a NameSpace object.
   Set oNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

 ' Open the file containing the shared item.
   Set oSharedItem = oNamespace.OpenSharedItem("D:\temp.msg")

' Save the item to the  folder.
   oSharedItem.SaveAs "D:\temp.txt"
```

Comment: You still having issue?

Comment: No, I got it working with a fuller version of the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the embedded message attachments as MSG files (`Attachment.SaveAsFile`), then open then using `Namespace.OpenSharedItem`.

If you want to access the embedded message attachments as messages without saving them, you'd need either Extended MAPI (`IAttach::OpenProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ, IID_IMessage, ...)`, C++ or Delphi only) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author - it exposes `Attachment.EmbeddedMsg` property).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I'm not familiar with Namespace.OpenSharedItem. How would I use it to open a file like "C:\documents\file.msg", then save it again as a text file?

Comment: Namespace.OpenShared‌​Item returns MailItem, call MailItem.SaveAs(.., olTxt). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869601.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: While searching SO for more information on  Namespace.OpenShared‌​‌​Item, it seems most of the answers came from you, Dmitry! You should include code examples in your answers -- don't be shy, we need your expertise!

Comment: There is really not much to include - you pass the file name to the function, get back MailItem.

Comment: Not everyone knows how to do that.